# there is a way to order empty element like null element?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I need to order a column and there are a lot of elements null or empty.The problem is null element are ordered differente from null element

```
SELECT s.name         
                   FROM Employee s
                 ORDER BY s.name desc
```

The result about is that employees with `name==null` are the first position, after there are the elements with name!=null (are a real name) and at the end there are the elements with `name empty`.

I want that the `name=null` and `name=empty` are treated in the same way and put all in the first result? Anyone can help me?

Comment: what do you mean with empty? Can you please post a small sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nulls first` or `nulls last` clause to determine where null values sort, i.e.

```
order by s.name desc nulls last
```

if you want `null` values to sort last rather than first or

```
order by s.name desc nulls first
```

if you want them so sort first

In Oracle, there is no such thing as an empty string that is separate from `null` so it isn't obvious what you mean when you say "empty".  My guess is that you mean a string that contains one or more spaces and nothing else.  If you want to eliminate spaces from the string before ordering so that a `name` of 1 space or 10 spaces is treated the same as `null`, you can `trim` the name

```
order by trim(s.name) desc nulls first
```

Note that this may affect performance if Oracle is using an index on `name` to do the sorting (unlikely in this particular case with no where clause but that may be important in the real query).  You may need a function-based index on `trim(name)` to support the ordering.